# list all tables from a database in syBase

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, sap-iq

In sql server 2012 i'm using

```
USE myDatabase;
GO
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.objects
WHERE   type = 'U';
```

Is it possible to do the same in syBase ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to get a list of all tables in the current database, you can filter the sysobjects table by type = ‘U’ e.g.:

```
select convert(varchar(30),o.name) AS table_name
from sysobjects o
where type = 'U'
order by table_name
```

Further [Reference](http://benohead.com/sybase-ase-list-tables-current-database-size/)

Here is an example of getting all table names in `MSSQL` or `SQL Server database`:

```
USE test; //SELECT DATABASE
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'base table'
```

or you can use sys.tables to get all table names from selected database as shown in following SQL query

```
USE test; //SELECT DATABASE
SELECT * FROM sys.tables
```

That's all on how to find all table names from database in SQL Server.

Comment: NB: Be careful with the Varchar size - I copied and pasted the above and found some of my table names were truncated so ensure you adjust as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Anywhere 16, this query works fine.

```
select * from sys.SYSTABLE
```

It gives a list of the table_names along with the information like table id, table page count, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In order to list all the tables and rows count, the following query can be used.

```
select convert(varchar(30),o.name) AS table_name,
row_count(db_id(), o.id) AS row_count
from sysobjects o
where type = 'U'
order by table_name
```

In order get a list of tables which has the table name like, use the following query.

Here `table_name` has to be replaced with your desired name.

```
select convert(varchar(30),o.name) AS table_name,
row_count(db_id(), o.id) AS row_count
from sysobjects o
where type = 'U' and o.name like '%table_name%'
order by table_name
```